# How can I add a minimize / maximize buttons in GUI made with Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I've create a GUI in "Qt Designer". Now I'd like to open a simple window with a minimize/maximize buttons in the top right corner.

```
from PyQt5 import uic
window = uic.loadUi("Video_Player.ui") # Video_Player.ui is the name of my GUI main file.
window.show()
```

should be something like this:

```
window.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint , True)
```

But I don't know how to set/define my Qt to make it work...?

Comment: use `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should firstly hide the Windows bar in this way:

```
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

And then add your own Minimize, Maximize and Close botton on QtDesigner. Finally for example you can make them work as follows in your code:

```
self.maxBtn = self.findChild(QPushButton,'Maximize_btn')
self.maxBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMaximized())

self.minBtn = self.findChild(QPushButton,'Minimize_btn')
self.minBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())

self.closeBtn = self.findChild(QPushButton,'Close_btn')
self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.setWindowFlags(_qt.FramelessWindowHint)`
This hides standard window's titlebar

Before
[image]

After
[image]